# How do to Install Script & Library with another Script in XX Documents PREVIOUSLY created?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How to charge multiple Docs white a Script and a Library (An ID of a Standalone Script )?

```
function GetListFilesInFolder() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("IDFOLDER").getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
  }
```

PUT HERE THE ACTION TO DO ( Mettre ici les modifs a effectuer )*****
 THE SCRIPT TO DO TO PASTE ID LIBRARY AND VERSION AND ALSO PASTE SCRIPT "Menu Library" IN EACH DOCUMENT *****
   -> Paste THE SCRIPT "Menu Library" AND ERASE EXISTING SCRIPT IF PRESENT
    The key TO PASTE "KEY ID OF THE STANDALONE SCRIPT" ex :"MsyugbZjzwbREFX21kTravXXXXXx3oCoSL"
 - Resources 
 - Library 
 - Search for a Library 
 -> Paste ID ( The key TO PASTE "KEY ID OF THE STANDALONE SCRIPT" )
 - Select 
 - Set in a version V1 SCRIPT "biblio"
 - Menu Manage Versions "V1" 
 - Save
 -Save and close files

```
 Logger.log("Done")
}
```

Version 3 11/07/2014 (2 Functions) {oninstall function () {onOpen (); onOpen} / / /function () {biblio.oninstall ();}"} 
Put only the functions in the "Biblio" Standalone Script

SCRIPT library "biblio" is called library, it is Unique It contains all the menus to create and execute Functions 
It is Unique and Key ID MsyugbZjzwbREFX21kTravXXXXXx3oCoSL 
Save a Version "V1" for example in File menu 
Manage Versions

SCRIPT of Appeal "Menu Library" is the same in all my Google Docs Document + + + + This script exactly HERE + + + +

In this SCRIPT "Menu Library " 
The key is entered MsyugbZjzwbREFX21kTravXXXXXx3oCoSL 
- Resources 
- Library

- Search for a Library 
  -> Paste ID
- Select
- Set in a version V1 SCRIPT "biblio" Previously
- Menu Manage Versions "V1"

  This SCRIPT "Menu Library" Call the SCRIPT library 
  The update of this script will be effective on all Documents 
  Calling the Script "biblio" V1

  All my Google Docs Document contains the script call "Menu Library" which call Unique Script "Biblio" 
  Benefit: Getting a single day, once the "Biblio" 
  In all Operational Documents Drive (featuring Script "Menu Library") `
  All my new Google Docs documents are a copy of a Virgin with the Script File Type "Menu Library "

++++++++++++++++++++++++
Container-bound SCRIPT ON EACH DOCUMENTS
++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
function oninstall() {
   onOpen();
 }

function onOpen() {
   biblio.oninstall();
 }
```

/**
++++++++++++++++++++++++
STANDALONE SCRIPT biblio
++++++++++++++++++++++++
*/

```
function onOpen() {
// Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('OAR ..')

.addItem('MAJ  Date + OAR', 'biblio.test')
.addItem('MAJ  Date  Auto', 'biblio.testdate')
.addItem('Ajout Texte QSP 28 OAR 2 Fois', 'biblio.AjoutQSP28JoursOAR2fois')

.addItem('URL Auto', 'biblio.urlauto')
.addItem('Macro en Cours ....', 'biblio.macroencours')
.addToUi();

 DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Données Patients ..')

 .addItem('Poids', 'biblio.message2')
 .addItem('Age', 'biblio.message2')
 .addItem('Taille', 'biblio.message2')
 .addToUi();

  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Ordo Paramedical ..')   
 .addItem('Accès Ordo Paramedical', 'biblio.accesordoparaA4')
 .addItem('Accès Ordo Paramedical ALD', 'biblio.accesordoparaA5')

 .addToUi();


 }

    function message2() { 

      DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert('Laurent inove tjrs et encore !    Developpement en Cours ...  Récupération des Données / Fiches Patients ...    Soyez Patients   !!!');


    // a creer
    }



    function urlauto() { 

      DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert('Developpement en Cours ... Veuillez Patientez ... Laurent travaille Déjà Beaucoup !');

    // a creer
    }



    function AjoutQSP28JoursOAR2fois() {       //Ajout QSP 28 Jours + OAR 2 fois
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();// or DocumentApp.openById(file.getId()); as in your example code
      var element = doc.getBody().findText("Le");

      var d=new Date();
      var s3=d.getFullYear();
      var s2=d.getMonth()+1;
      var s1=d.getDate();
      var s4 =s2+2 
      var s5 =s1-10
      var s6 =s2+3
      if(s1<10) {
      s1=("0"+s1).slice(s1.length-1);
      } 
      if(s1>10) {
      s1=(""+s1).slice(s1.length-1);
      }
      if(s2<10) {
      s2=("0"+s2).slice(s2.length-1);
      } 
      if(s2>10) {
      s2=(""+s2).slice(s2.length-1);
      }

        var start = element.getStartOffset();
        var text = element.getElement().asText();
        text.editAsText().deleteText(3,12);
        text.replaceText("Le ","Le " +[s1,s2,s3].join('/') + "\n" + "\n" +"QSP 28 Jours" +"\n"+ "OAR  2 fois");
        text.editAsText().setFontSize(14,38,12);  

     }


    function accesordoparaA4() {
     DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert('Developpement en Cours ... Veuillez Patientez ... Laurent travaille Déjà Beaucoup !');
       // Open a document by ID.
     var doc = DocumentApp.openById("");
     }

    function accesordoparaA5() {
     DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert('Developpement en Cours ... Veuillez Patientez ... Laurent travaille Déjà Beaucoup !');
     }
```

Comment: There is no way to programmatically change the content of container-bounds scripts. A work-around is described in one of the comments on Google Apps Script Issue 40, [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=40#c83). The idea is to update the script in your "virgin" template file, then use this script to create new versions of each of your target documents and copy the content from the old doc to the new one. Then end result would be that you have the same document content, with the new script code. Problem: Doc ID would have changed, URL would change.

Comment: yes i am ok for your answwer.I'd think this solution has already . The other problem for me that i lost the document historic and the ID of 2000 Docs change . I use URL and ID in Google contact for the Links .but i don't despair i'am certain that they are a solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically change the content of container-bounds scripts.

A work-around is described in comment 83 on Google Apps Script Issue 40, [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=40#c83).

The idea is to update the script in your "virgin" template file, then use the script from the comment to create new versions of each of your target documents, copying the content from the old doc to the new one. Then end result would be that you have the same document content, with the new script code.

A problem with this approach is that you would end up with new documents; the Doc ID would have changed, and the URL for each document would change. This would be a problem for any cross-document references or collaborators.

Comment: Thanks Mogsdad . Also a problem for me is that i lost the history  of the files when i copy old files in new with the good wrapper script on board.Is they're a solution to know in a direcory contains 300 files which files contains Script an d the name of the script ?

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to determine which documents contain scripts. Only stand-alone scripts are visible as "files".

Comment: Thanks a lot . it's too bad !!! I have 2500 documents with embedded script and others without .I processed would only docs without embedded script part.